# Error :java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

```
<activity
    android:name="com.luckyxmobile.timers4meplus.activity.WidgetConfigActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicator.Dark">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />

        <category android:name="com.jakewharton.android.viewpagerindicator.sample.SAMPLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>


<style name="Theme.PageIndicator.Dark" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="tpi_tabPadding">12dp</item>
    <item name="tpi_tabRipple">@style/DarkTabRippleStyle</item>
    <item name="tpi_indicatorHeight">3dp</item>
    <item name="tpi_indicatorColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/DarkTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tpi_mode">scroll</item>
</style>
```

The above is  theme and style.When I run the app,show this error. I think maybe it should be "Theme.AppCompat" not "android:Theme",but not sure!

Comment: Show your `Launcher activity`, the main activity which gets started?

Comment: Laucher activity is others,not this activity

Comment: It looks like that you are extending `activity` to `AppCompat` but the theme of that activity is not `Theme.AppCompat` . Please check that

Comment: try extending `AppCompatActivity` rather than `Activity` for `WidgetConfigActivity`

Comment: @Mustansar Saeed I will try ,thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Whats your logcat throws**

```
Error :java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity
```

I guess, you need to extends `AppCompatActivity`

```
public class WidgetConfigActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  // ...
}
```

> AppCompatActivity is from the appcompat-v7 library. Principally, this
>   offers a backport of the action bar. Since the native action bar was
>   added in API Level 11, you do not need AppCompatActivity for that.
>   However, current versions of appcompat-v7 also add a limited backport
>   of the Material Design aesthetic, in terms of the action bar and
>   various widgets.

You can use `Theme.AppCompat` instead of `android:Theme` .

Comment: `public class WidgetConfigActivity extends AppCompatActivity ` . sure,I think maybe the error is  parent of style

Comment: @Lollipop same error ?? Problem is your `parent="android:Theme"`

Comment: yeah,I think the parent of style should be `Theme.AppCompat`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101750/discussion-between-lollipop-and-intellij-amiya).